# How to set the LDFLAGS in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, ld, ldflags

I set the CFLAGS in CMake by CMAKE_C_FLAGS.
Is something like this to set LDFLAGS?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want:

A) If you want to specify which libraries to link to, you can use [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to find libs and then use [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) and [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to.

Of course, it is often worth the effort to write a good [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) script, which nicely adds "imported" libraries with [add_library( YourLib IMPORTED )](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) with correct locations, and platform/build specific pre- and suffixes. You can then simply refer to 'YourLib' and use target_link_libraries.

B) If you wish to specify particular linker-flags, e.g. '-mthreads' or '-Wl,--export-all-symbols' with MinGW-GCC, you can use [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html). There are also two similar but undocumented flags for modules, shared or static libraries:

```
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
```

Comment: And CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS for static library: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.html

Comment: Just a link to the recent CMake3.0 description: [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html). Note that the MODULE/SHARED/STATIC flags are already documented (though pretty vaguely).

Comment: What is the Module flag for?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I think it is used for clang module library in macOS.

Comment: How do you use the defines? `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS += "-Mprogram.mapfile"` fails.

Comment: cmake has recently added add_link_options(), similar to add_compile_options() - see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_link_options.html

Answer (score 26):

Look at:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to add a flag to *every* link, e.g. `-fsanitize=address` then I would not recommend using `CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS`. Even with them all set it still doesn't use the flag when linking a framework on OSX, and maybe in other situations. Instead use `link_libraries()`:

```
add_compile_options("-fsanitize=address")
link_libraries("-fsanitize=address")
```

This works for everything.

Comment: Is add_compile_options necessary if I just want to set linker flags?

Comment: That's for now the best and cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify linker flags in [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries).

Answer (score 4):

For linking against libraries see [Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6088646/3162383).

For linker flags - the following 4 CMake variables:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
```

can be easily manipulated for different configs (debug, release...) with the [ucm_add_linker_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_add_linker_flags) macro of [ucm](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm)