# How can I add linker flag for libraries with CMake?

Tags: cmake

When linking a binary I can use `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to add a flag (let's say `-Wl,-as-needed`). However, if I link a library this extra flag will not be taken into account. I would need something like `CMAKE_LIB_LINKER_FLAGS` but I can't find it.

How should I do this?

Comment: take a look at CMakeCache.txt file. There are various CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS variables (I do not have cmake currently so i cannot check). Choose the one you want

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Note**: modern CMake has a better solution than mentioned below (see updates for details).

You can use [CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS) like:

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--as-needed")
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/cmake-how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt) looks like related.

**UPD**
Thanks to @Bruce Adams who points out that since v3.13 CMake has [special command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_link_options.html) for such purpose: `add_link_options`.

**UPD 2**
Thanks to @Alex Reinking who points out that modern CMake doesn't recommend using global settings. It is suggested to give the preference to the property settings before the global ones, so instead of `add_link_options` that has a global scope, the `target_link_options` should be used. See Alex's answer for details.

Comment: Note that CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS is for dynamic libraries. For static libraries use CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS instead.

Comment: Don't use directory commands!! Prefer `target_link_options` to `add_link_options` in CMake 3.13+. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @AlexReinking, thank for your comment! I've updated the answer and added this information.

Comment: What about `LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE`?

Comment: **Wl** "-Wl,--as-needed" means to pass `--as-needed` directly to linker

Answer (score 18):

**This is how you add linker flags to a target in modern CMake (3.13+):**

```
# my_tgt can be an executable, library, or module.
target_link_options(my_tgt PRIVATE "LINKER:-as-needed")
```

Note that CMake always passes flags to the configured *compiler*. Thus, to forward your intended link flags to the linker, you must use the `LINKER:` prefix. CMake will take care of expanding it to `-Wl,-as-needed` on GCC, and to `-Xlinker -as-needed` on Clang.

See the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this problem is related to the one I had in CLION. I solved it by adding

```
{set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES -ljpeg)}
```

to CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS VARIABLE THAT WAY.** [The documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html?highlight=standard_libraries#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_STANDARD_LIBRARIES) clearly states _"This variable should not be set by project code. It is meant to be set by CMake’s platform information modules for the current toolchain, or by a toolchain file when used with CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE."_

Answer (score 3):

In CMake 3.10.2, the suggested answer of
`set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--as-needed")`
did not work for me.  The workaround I employed was to use `set_target_properties` instead.

My *CMakeLists.txt* file had a line of this sort:
`add_library(libraryname MODULE a.cc b.cc c.cc)`

After that line, I added this:
`set_target_properties(libraryname PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-znodelete")`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ucm_add_linker_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_add_linker_flags) macro of [ucm](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm) - it deals with appending linker flags to the appropriate CMake variables.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to add your linker option **without** the "-Wl,", namely:

Good:

```
-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-fstack-protector"
```

Wrong:

```
-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-fstack-protector"
```

Answer (score -1):

target_link_libraries(*target-name* PRIVATE -lexpat)

i used this for linking the XML dependencies in my project. replace -lexpat with -l(*library name*)