# How to build a C++ make project using specific LDFLAGS (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, c++11, cmake, compiler-flags

I have a project that needs to be built using cmake and make. However, I want the project to use libc++ (since its written in C++11) so I need to set the right linker flags. Is there a way I can pass the following flags via command line?

```
 LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
```

Or do I need to edit my CMakeLists.txt file? If so how can I add this to the file?

Answer (score 0):

For the more complex linker flags use

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib)
```

To add a library search directory (-L) simply add

```
link_directories(/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib)
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534867/5393249) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28606916/5393249) answer