# Android NDK Linker failure for armeabi-v7a: "PLT offset too large, try linking with --long-plt"

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, llvm-clang

When trying to build a signed APK, it fails with ~100 lines repeating:

```
Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: PLT offset too large, try linking with --long-plt
```

I've added --long-plt to the arguments:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        ...
        arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static', '-Wl,--long-plt'
        cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything.

It works with non-signed (debug) apk generation and works with `arm64-v8a`.

I'm dealing with >1GB of native code, so I'm guessing that's the main reason.

It seems there is almost no documentation or search result regarding this.

Does `--long-plt` need to be put somewhere else? If not, is there another setting that can be changed? Or would splitting the code into separate libraries help?

Here's the CMakeLists.txt for reference:

```
string(REPLACE "." "/" JAVA_GEN_SUBDIR ${JAVA_GEN_PACKAGE})
set(JAVA_GEN_DIR ${Project_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/java/${JAVA_GEN_SUBDIR}/../../../../../generated)

# configure import libs
set(distribution_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/distribution)

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Note: One could use a 'GLOB' here, but newly added source files won't auto-regen build files
# After adding files, you'd need to 'touch' the CMakeLists.txt to re-gen

# SWIG required for build. Easy install is "brew install swig"
#Site: http://swig.org
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

# Remove old java files, in case we don't need to generate some of them anymore
#file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${JAVA_GEN_DIR})

# Ensure file recognized as C++ (otherwise, exported as C file)
set_property(SOURCE src/main/cpp/${LIBRARY_NAME}.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

# Setup SWIG flags and locations
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -c++ -package ${JAVA_GEN_PACKAGE})
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${JAVA_GEN_DIR})

# Export a wrapper file to Java, and link with the created C++ library
swig_add_module(${LIBRARY_NAME}_Wrapper java ${SWIG_I_FILE})
swig_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME}_Wrapper ${LIBRARY_NAME})



# Include a location to the header files
include_directories(
    src/main/cpp
    ${NativeLibPath}
    ${LUAPATH}
    )

set(LUAPATH ${NativeLibPath}/lua)

    file(GLOB ALL_SOURCE_FILES
        "src/main/cpp/*.cpp"
        "${NativeLibPath}/*.cpp"
        "${LUAPATH}/*.c"
    )

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             ${LIBRARY_NAME}

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides the list of files to compile.
             ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES} )

target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PRIVATE)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.
target_link_libraries(
                       # Specifies the target library.
                       ${LIBRARY_NAME}
                       android
                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}
                     )
```

Comment: That doesn't actually build: `CMake Error: The source directory ".../app/--long-plt" does not exist.`

Comment: My mistake, I misread the documentation then.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Have you tried to modify flags directly in CMakeLists.txt? There is a chance you overwrite them there.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Added (most of) the `CMakeLists.txt`. I don't think it's doing anything funky that should affect the flags. Is it possible I should/could set the flags there rather than in gradle?

Comment: I am unable to test it myself, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534867/74739) seems to suggest a way to accomplish it.

Comment: Try `'-Wl', '--long-plt'` instead of `'-Wl,--long-plt'`

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup That doesn't compile. `-Wl,--long-plt` is one command, not two.

Answer (score -1):

I agree there is not so much documentation on internet, even if we can find some.

First, try to modify your configuration file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        ...
        arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
        cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-Wl,--long-plt"
    }
}
```

Let me know, if it changes anything?

Comment: That's the same as what I have, except you separated `-Wl` from `--long-plt`, which doesn't compile.

Comment: That also won't compile... `'-Wl,--long-plt'` is one command.

Comment: True, I miswritten it; fixed; could you try again? I guess these option should be pass to the gcc itself, which will gives to the linker, just after.
If it doesn't work, you may try setting environment variable **export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS -Wl,--long-plt"** or maybe **export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS --long-plt"**

Comment: That also doesn't even compile. Where would you put the LDFlags?

Comment: On your Terminal / CLI where you launch cmake.

Comment: Did you try it? How do you launch the apk creation?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. Tried doing `set (LDFLAGS "${LDFLAGS} -Wl,--long-plt")` with various configuration and nothing changed.

Comment: And what about **set (LDFLAGS "${LDFLAGS} --long-plt")** (because -Wl is initially an option for the gcc to give when calling the linker, here it is the environment variable directly used by the linker).