# Can cmake compile directly from source files to binary?

Tags: gcc, cmake

cmake compiles first the .c files to .o files, and then links them together:

```
gcc a.c -o a.c.o
gcc b.c -o b.c.o
gcc c.c -o c.c.o
gcc a.c.o b.c.o c.c.o -o a.out
```

That instead of compiling directly from source files to binary:

```
gcc a.c b.c c.c -o a.out
```

Normally I would have used link-time-optimization (`-flto`) to allow the compiler to do cross-binary optimization, but unfortunately, I have to use an old compiler that doesn't support link-time-optimization.

That means, that if I use cmake, my binary comes out 3 times larger than if I compile directly from source files to binary, because of the lack of cross-binary optimization

Do you know a way to make cmake compile directly from source files to binary, or do you know an alternative way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use [a custom command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) or [target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) and use the COMMAND param to build your source files.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if you have problems like the binary being 3 times larger when utilizing CMake you need to look at the complete build process.

First check if the compiler/linker options are really same: [Using CMake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)

If they all match you can - to find out what sections are actually larger - compare the map files of your output in the CMake and non-CMake case. In CMake you need to add `-Wl,-Map=<TARGET_NAME>.map` to your linker flags. How to add linker flags see: [CMake: How to set the LDFLAGS in CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/cmake-how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt)

Or alternatively use `nm` or `size` on your `a.out`: [Tool to analyze size of ELF sections and symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720340/tool-to-analyze-size-of-elf-sections-and-symbol)

Last you try activating other optimization options of your linker (the generic `-O` option should be supported even by older compilers). See also: [Remove useless files, includes, global variables and functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696894/remove-useless-files-includes-global-variables-and-functions-in-c)

#### `.c` vs `.o` and GNU on Windows

There should not be a difference between giving the source files or the object files to `gcc`. But if you're using the GNU toolchain on Windows you may have been stumbled across a workaround in [Windows-GNU.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake#L131):

```
# The gcc/collect2/ld toolchain does not use response files
# internally so we cannot pass long object lists.  Instead pass
# the object file list in a response file to the archiver to put
# them in a temporary archive.  Hand the archive to the linker.
```

This workaround does result in:

```
gcc a.c -o a.c.o
gcc b.c -o b.c.o
gcc c.c -o c.c.o
rm objects.a
ar cr a.c.o b.c.o c.c.o -o objects.a
gcc objects.a -o a.out
```

The problem is the `ar` call in the middle. If CMake would take the `.o` files directly you would be fine.

You can overwrite this workaround by setting `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` back to its default after your `project()` command:

```
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

Additional reference: [CMake: use a custom linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867745/cmake-use-a-custom-linker)