# Instruct CMake to use CXX and CXXFLAGS when driving link?

Tags: gcc, linker, cmake, solaris

We are catching link errors on Solaris with makefiles generated by CMake 3.6.2. In the testing below, we are using GCC and not SunCC. From the looks of it, CMake is applying our options inconsistently:

**Typical compile command**

```
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cryptopp-object.dir/cpu.cpp.o
/bin/c++ -fPIC -march=native -m64 -Wa,--divide -o CMakeFiles/cryptopp-object.dir/cryptlib.cpp.o 
-c /export/home/jwalton/cryptopp/cpu.cpp
```

**Abbreviated link command**

```
/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/bench1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/bench2.cpp.o
...
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/fipstest.cpp.o  -o cryptest.exe  libcryptopp.a -lnsl -lsocket
```

**Typical link error**

```
ld: fatal: file CMakeFiles/cryptopp-object.dir/cryptlib.cpp.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Notice the file was compiled with `-march=native -m64` (its a 64-bit capable machine and kernel), but the link invocation is missing it (the default is 32-bit on Solaris).

Attempting to search for *["cmake use CXXFLAGS link"](http://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+use+CXXFLAGS+for+link)* is producing too much irrelevant noise, and I'm not having much luck finding the `CMakeList.txt` option. I also want to avoid duplicating the work into `LDFLAGS`, or performing the work of reformatting the options (`CXXFLAGS` option `-Wl,-x` becomes `LDFLAGS` option `-x`).

How do I instruct CMake to use both CXX and CXXFLAGS when driving link?

---

I found [Running a different program for the linker](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2003-June/003967.html) on the CMake users mailing list, but it does not feel right to me (also, the problem and context are slightly different). It also does not work.

Here is a small example:

```
PROJECT(foo)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "purify <CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo foo.cxx)
```

---

I also found [Setting global link flags](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011515.html) on the mailing list. It does not work, either.

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Comment: Does CMake use `LDFLAGS`?  Or see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077414/cmake-how-to-set-the-ldflags-in-cmakelists-txt

Comment: @AndrewHenle - According to some Camke user posts, it appears so. However, I'm not a guy who should b answering questions like that since I'm too inexperienced with Cmake.

Comment: Probably related. In general, I wouldn't try to add CXXFLAGS to the linker. Just pass, what you actually need (`-x`) to the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS. Check with `make VERBOSE=1` whether the added flags appear or not.

Comment: @usr1234567 - Forgive my ignorance... What does CMake do with Sanitizer builds? The sanitizer flags are supposed to be passed through the compiler driver, and the driver is supposed to pass the flag along with the appropriate libraries to the linker. We are explicitly told *not* to pass sanitizer libs to the linker; the compiler driver should handle it.