# Difference between add_compile_options and SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS...)

Tags: cmake, compiler-options

This question is related to [Instruct Cmake to use CXX and CXXFLAGS when driving link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39497813/608639) In the former question, we are trying to instruct CMake to use `CXXFLAGS` when it invokes the linker.

***add_compile_options***

We found that the following code

```
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
    add_definitions(-foo)
else()
    add_compile_options(-foo)
endif()

message(STATUS, "CXXFLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

produces the output

```
CXXFLAGS:
```

***SET CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS***

We found that the following code

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -foo" )

message(STATUS, "CXXFLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

produces the output

```
CXXFLAGS: -foo
```

***Questions***

We found CMake would create object files using `-foo` in both cases. So `-foo` is definitely making its way into `CXXFLAGS`.

What is the difference between the first set of CMake code and the second set of CMake code?

Why is `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` unset in one instance, and set in the other instance?

Comment: In case versions matter: `cmake --version` returns `cmake version 3.6.2`.

Comment: @usr1234567 - Yeah, sorry about the questions. The folks who wanted CMake are not maintaining it, so the responsibility now falls on me. I know nearly nothing about CMake because I use GNUmake and write my own makefiles. I *regret* accepting those CMake patches... And yes, I will get the questions edited. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

- `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is used to add flags for all C++ targets. That's handy to pass general arguments like warning levels or to selected required C++ standards. It has no effect on C or Fortran targets and the user might pass additional flags.
- `add_compile_options` adds the options to all targets within the directory and its sub-directories. This is handy if you have a library in a directory and you want to add options to all the targets related to the library, but unrelated to all other targets. Additionally, `add_compile_options` can handle arguments with *[generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)*. The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_compile_options.html) explicitly states, that

> This command can be used to add any options, but alternative commands
>   exist to add preprocessor definitions (`target_compile_definitions()`
>   and `add_definitions()`) or include directories
>   (`target_include_directories()` and `include_directories()`).

- `add_definitions` is intended to pass pre-processor values of the type `-DFOO -DBAR=32` (`/D`  on Windows) which defines and sets pre-processor variables. You could pass any flag, but the flags of the above form are detected and added to `[COMPILE_DEFINITIONS][2]` property, which you can later read and change. Here, you can use *generator expressions*, too. The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_definitions.html) mentions scopes for directories, targets and source files.

For a given target, CMake will collect all flags from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, the target's and directory's `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` and from all `add_compile_options` which affect the target.
`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are not altered by the other commands or vice versa. This would violate the scope of these commands.

Comment: Thanks @usr1234567. At the call site, when `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` was printed with `message(STAUS, ...)`, why did CMake not yield the values added with `target_compile_definitions` and `add_definitions`? Why were they not printed?

Comment: @jww: Because `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` doesn't accumulate values added with `target_compile_definitions` and `add_definitions`. It is *generator* who forms compiler call and collects all its options: from variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`, from target's property `COMPILE_DEFINITION` and so on.

Comment: @jww: I added a paragraph concerning your question.

Comment: Thanks again @usr1234567. One last question then with respect to Make variables and generators... If the generators won't yield the values, then how does one do things like [instruct CMake to use accumulated flags during linking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39497813)?

Comment: @jww: That's a question of it's own.