# fatal error: unordered_map: No such file or directory (C++ 98, gcc 4.8.5, using CMAKE)

Tags: c++, cmake, unordered-map

gcc throws fatal error: unordered_map.h: No such file or directory on #include . I am using CMAKE, and gcc 4.8.5 compiler.

```
main:

#include "a.h"
...
void main() { ...}


a.h:
#include <unordered_map>
```

Comment: Did you compile with c++0x/c++11 enabled?

Comment: [`<unordered_map>` is a c++11 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if you set the standard to something more modern it'll work

Comment: Have you read https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html ?

Comment: `unordered_map` requires C++11 source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: This [answer may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505520/332733) as to how to set a flag in Cmake

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to cross reference, but it says that unordered_map was introduced in C++11.

Source: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: The website is not wrong, it's a c++11 and newer feature

Comment: Fixed the wording following confirmation