# OGRE 3D shared libraries linked with CMake not found when executing binary on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, compilation, shared-libraries

I am currently porting my OGRE 3D-based C++ application from pure Windows to Linux. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and a manually build OGRE 3D 1.12.1 which was compiled and installed to **/usr/local/lib** and **/usr/local/lib/OGRE** which is the default install location.

See:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/local/lib/
total 9,2M
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4,0K Aug  3 11:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4,0K Feb 10 01:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreBites.so -> libOgreBites.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  337K Aug  3 11:33 libOgreBites.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  681K Aug  3 11:21 libOgreGLSupport.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreHLMS.so -> libOgreHLMS.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  177K Aug  3 11:36 libOgreHLMS.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreMain.so -> libOgreMain.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5,7M Aug  3 11:20 libOgreMain.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    33 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreMeshLodGenerator.so -> libOgreMeshLodGenerator.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  362K Aug  3 11:34 libOgreMeshLodGenerator.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreOverlay.so -> libOgreOverlay.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  576K Aug  3 11:28 libOgreOverlay.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreProperty.so -> libOgreProperty.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   79K Aug  3 11:34 libOgreProperty.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Aug  3 11:38 libOgreRTShaderSystem.so -> libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1,3M Aug  3 11:31 libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.12.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4,0K Aug  3 11:38 OGRE
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4,0K Aug  3 11:38 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x  4 root staff 4,0K Jun 23 15:36 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff 4,0K Feb 10 01:12 python3.6

$ ls -lah /usr/local/lib/OGRE
total 1,2M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4,0K Aug  3 11:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4,0K Aug  3 11:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K Aug  3 11:38 cmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Aug  3 11:38 Codec_FreeImage.so -> Codec_FreeImage.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70K Aug  3 11:26 Codec_FreeImage.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Aug  3 11:38 Codec_STBI.so -> Codec_STBI.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200K Aug  3 11:26 Codec_STBI.so.1.12.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Aug  3 11:38 RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so -> RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so.1.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 886K Aug  3 11:26 RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so.1.12.1
```

My CMake build is finding all the required libraries (also the ones in /usr/local/lib/OGRE), but after I have compiled my binaries, my Ubuntu is unable to find the shared libraries located under /usr/local/lib/OGRE:

```
$ ldd client 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2fde2000)
    libhoibase.so => /home/thomas/game/build/hoibase/libhoibase.so (0x00007fbcb3b0c000)
    libOgreMain.so.1.12.1 => /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.12.1 (0x00007fbcb343e000)
    libOgreBites.so.1.12.1 => /usr/local/lib/libOgreBites.so.1.12.1 (0x00007fbcb31fc000)
    libOgreOverlay.so.1.12.1 => /usr/local/lib/libOgreOverlay.so.1.12.1 (0x00007fbcb2f8a000)
    libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.12.1 => /usr/local/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.12.1 (0x00007fbcb2c77000)
    RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so.1.12.1 => not found
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbcb2945000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbcb25bc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbcb221e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbcb2006000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbcb1c15000)
    libCGAL.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCGAL.so.13 (0x00007fbcb19f6000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fbcb17ef000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fbcb156e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbcb136a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbcb114b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fbcb0e13000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007fbcb0baa000)
    libXaw.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXaw.so.7 (0x00007fbcb0936000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fbcb0682000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fbcb037b000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007fbcb012b000)
    libsndio.so.6.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.6.1 (0x00007fbcaff1b000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fbcafd09000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fbcafaff000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fbcaf8fc000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fbcaf6ec000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fbcaf4e1000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007fbcaf2dd000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fbcaf0d7000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007fbcaeed5000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007fbcaecc6000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007fbcaeabe000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fbcae87f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbcae677000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbcb4350000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fbcae44f000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fbcae247000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fbcae02c000)
    libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007fbcade13000)
    libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0x00007fbcadc01000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fbcad9cf000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbcad7b2000)
    libpulsecommon-11.1.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-11.1.so (0x00007fbcad534000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fbcad2e7000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fbcad0d2000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fbcacec8000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fbcaccc2000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fbcacaba000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fbcac8b6000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fbcac6b0000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fbcac42c000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fbcac222000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007fbcabfa9000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007fbcabda3000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbcabb7d000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fbcab961000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fbcab646000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fbcab42c000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007fbcab1b5000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fbcaafac000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fbcaad81000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fbcaaad8000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbcaa8bd000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fbcaa6a8000)
```

What am I doing wrong? What is  the trick to make Ubuntu find my **RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so.1.12.1**?

Comment: You might want to add a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/ogre.conf` containing a line with the path `/usr/local/lib/OGRE`. After that you should run `ldconfig` once to update its cache.

Comment: The problem, is that `/usr/local/lib/OGRE` isn't in the *run-time linker* path. Either solve it as mentioned above (by editing the run-time linker configuration) or tell the linker the path with the option `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/OGRE` when building.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently porting my OGRE 3D-based C++ application from pure Windows to Linux. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and a manually build OGRE 3D 1.12.1 which was compiled and installed to /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/lib/OGRE which is the default install location...

As others have stated, the various OGRE libraries cannot be found by the runtime linker. When executing in the build folder, you usually use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to provide the override you need to put a library on path.

Once you perform a `make install` the binary should be able to find the library because either (1) library is in a well known path; or (2) binary has a `RUNPATH` with the location of the library. Sometimes you use (3) use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after install. Doing (3) kind of sucks and you should avoid it.

It sounds like the program `client` lacks a `RUNPATH` with the location of OGRE libraries. `client` should have a `DT_RUNPATH` with `/usr/local/lib/OGRE` (and *not* a `DT_RPATH`). Also see [Is there a way to inspect the current rpath on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2836330/608639).

You want a `DT_RUNPATH` because `DT_RUNPATH` allows `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides. `DT_RPATH` *does not* allow `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides.

If the `RUNPATH` is not there, then add it with `LDFLAGS += -Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib/OGRE -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. In CMake, you add linker flags using `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS`. `-Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib/OGRE -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` should be added to each one you are using. Also see [How to set the LDFLAGS in CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077414/608639).

Note: you probably need to add the options to `LDFLAGS` for both `client` and the OGRE libraries since the OGRE libraries probably have dependencies on one another.

---

Something a little more flexible for you may be to use `-Wl,-R,'$$ORIGIN/../lib/OGRE' -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. `$ORIGIN` is where your program is located, and it tells the runtime linker to look in the relative directory `../lib/OGRE` for its libraries. It allows you to move your program (in `.../bin/`) and libraries (in `.../lib/` and `.../lib/OGRE`) around on the filesystem.

---

You can thank the glibc folks for the Linux path problems that have plagued Linux for the last 25 years or so. They think it is normal to compile against a version of a library, link against a version of the library, and then load the wrong version of the library at runtime or lose the library at runtime. They should get a [Darwin Award](https://darwinawards.com/) for not fixing the idiotic decision.

(Making the wrong descision was OK since we all make mistakes. However, they have never fixed it. Instead they allow these problems to fester for decades.)

Comment: Thank you jww, Lars Fischer and Some programmer dude. Your explanations helped me a lot to successfully get out of Linux's dependency hell ;-)

jww, I have set the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS and now everything works as expected. But I am not sure what to do when I am e.g. building an DEB package. In this case, the problematic shared libraries would be under e.g. */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE*. Is there a best practice for deployments?